# How to use react-pose with @reach/router in React Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-tsx, reach-router, react-pose

In my React app I'm trying to convert a JS `react-pose`-`@reach/router` sample to TypeScript, but it does not work.

Here are the relating typings in `react-pose`:

```
import { ComponentType, HTMLProps } from 'react';
import { PoseElementProps } from './components/PoseElement/types';
import { DomPopmotionConfig } from 'popmotion-pose';
declare type DomPopmotionConfigFactory<T> = (props: PoseElementProps & T) => DomPopmotionConfig;
export declare type ComponentFactory<T> = (poseConfig?: DomPopmotionConfig | DomPopmotionConfigFactory<T>) => ComponentType<PoseElementProps & T>;
export declare type Posed = {
    <T>(component: ComponentType<T>): ComponentFactory<T>;
    [key: string]: ComponentFactory<HTMLProps<any>>;
};
declare const posed: Posed;
export default posed;
```

The JS example looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Link, Location } from '@reach/router';
import posed, { PoseGroup } from 'react-pose';
import Home from './pages/home';
import About from './pages/about';

import './styles.css';

const RouteContainer = posed.div({
  enter: { opacity: 1, delay: 300, beforeChildren: 300 },
  exit: { opacity: 0 }
});

const PosedRouter = ({ children }) => (
  <Location>
    {({ location }) => (
      <PoseGroup>
        <RouteContainer key={location.key}>
          <Router location={location}>{children}</Router>
        </RouteContainer>
      </PoseGroup>
    )}
  </Location>
);

const App = () => (
  <div id="site-container">
    <header>
      <h1>Route transitions with Pose and Reach Router</h1>
    </header>
    <div id="content-container">
      <ul id="site-nav">
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <PosedRouter>
        <Home path="/" />
        <About path="/about" />
      </PosedRouter>
    </div>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Source: https://popmotion.io/pose/examples/route-transitions-reach-router/

And I'm stuck here:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Router, Link, Location } from '@reach/router';
import { ComponentFactory } from 'react-pose/lib/posed';
import posed, { PoseGroup } from 'react-pose';

const RouteContainer: ComponentFactory<React.HTMLProps<any>> = posed.div({
    enter: { opacity: 1, delay: 300, beforeChildren: 300 },
    exit: { opacity: 0 }
});

const PosedRouter: Location = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => (
    <Location>
        {({ location }) => (
            <PoseGroup>
                <RouteContainer key={location.key}>
                    <Router location={location}>{children}</Router>
                </RouteContainer>
            </PoseGroup>
        )}
    </Location>
);
```

On `<RouteContainer key={location.key}>` it says:

> Type 'ComponentType<{ [key: string]: any; children?: any; pose?:
>   string | string[] | undefined; _pose?: string | string[] | undefined;
>   initialPose?: string | string[] | undefined; withParent?: boolean |
>   undefined; onPoseComplete?: ((pose: string | string[]) => any) |
>   undefined; onValueChange?: { ...; } | undefined; innerR...' is not
>   assignable to type 'ComponentFactory>'.   Type
>   'ComponentClass<{ [key: string]: any; children?: any; pose?: string |
>   string[] | undefined; _pose?: string | string[] | undefined;
>   initialPose?: string | string[] | undefined; withParent?: boolean |
>   undefined; onPoseComplete?: ((pose: string | string[]) => any) |
>   undefined; onValueChange?: { ...; } | undefined; inner...' is not
>   assignable to type 'ComponentFactory>'.
>       Type 'ComponentClass<{ [key: string]: any; children?: any; pose?: string | string[] | undefined; _pose?: string | string[] | undefined;
>   initialPose?: string | string[] | undefined; withParent?: boolean |
>   undefined; onPoseComplete?: ((pose: string | string[]) => any) |
>   undefined; onValueChange?: { ...; } | undefined; inner...' provides no
>   match for the signature '(poseConfig?: DomPopmotionConfig |
>   DomPopmotionConfigFactory> | undefined):
>   ComponentType<{ [key: string]: any; children?: any; pose?: string |
>   string[] | undefined; _pose?: string | string[] | undefined; ... 4
>   more ...; innerRef?: { ...; } | ... 1 more ... | undefined; } &
>   PoseContextProps & HTMLProps<...>>'.

This is confusing to me, because the typings look correct. I don't want to use anonymous signatures and stay strong on typing, here.

How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that on the first render `location.key` is undefined. That's likely why you're getting the cryptic error message making reference to something being undefined. I used `location.pathname`. It seemed to work without any issues. It would be great to use `location.key`, but in `react-router-dom@5.0.1`, it's undefined on the first render.